How to forward cookies set by an API to the browser in SSR with Next.js?
I'm working on a Next.js application, and I have a method that calls an API from the server. This API sets a cookie, and I need to forward this cookie to the browser.
However, I’m facing a challenge:

Server Actions: I can set cookies from server actions, but this requires triggering the method from the client side.
Route Handlers: Alternatively, I can create a route handler, but this also needs to be called from the client side.

This approach doesn't seem to leverage SSR effectively. Where is the SSR in this method? Is there a better way to achieve this in Next.js that fits within the SSR paradigm? Any guidance would be appreciated.
for example
export async function getData(): Promise<ServerState> {
  const res = await fetch(`${getApiUrl()}/user`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Cookie: cookies().toString(),
    },
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    return {
      status: ServerStateStatus.ERROR,
      message: JSON.stringify(res),
    };
  }

  // Revalidate user requests to pull in new payload
  revalidateTag('user');

//here i am setting the response cookie so when i am doing this then i can't call it from server as in prod it throws error setting cookie is not allowed in server but when i am calling it from client it behaves like server action so works fine. 
setServerCookies(response.headers.getSetCookie());

  return {
    status: ServerStateStatus.SUCCESS,
    message: 'got the data',
  };
}

//for ref

'use server';

import { ServerState, ServerStateStatus } from '@common-utils';
import { ResponseCookie } from 'next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/cookies';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

export interface Cookie {
  name: string;
  value: string;
  [attr: string]: unknown;
}

export const setServerCookies = async (cookieArray: string[]) => {
  cookieArray.forEach((cookieString) => {
    const cookie: Cookie = { name: '', value: '' };

    const parts = cookieString.split(';');

    // Process the first part to extract name and value
    const firstPart = parts.shift() || '';
    const [name, value] = firstPart.trim().split('=');
    cookie.name = name.trim();
    cookie.value = value.trim();

    parts.forEach((part) => {
      const keyValue = part.trim().split('=');

      // If there's no '=', it means it's a boolean attribute (e.g., httpOnly, secure)
      if (keyValue.length === 1) {
        const key = keyValue[0].trim();
        cookie[key.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + key.slice(1)] = true;
      } else {
        const key = keyValue[0].trim();
        const value = keyValue.slice(1).join('=').trim();

        // Convert 'expires' field to Date if key is 'expires'
        if (key === 'expires') {
          cookie.expires = new Date(value);
        } else {
          cookie[key] = value;
        }
      }
    });

    // Set the cookie using Next.js cookies API
    cookies().set(cookie as ResponseCookie);
  });
};


I have done a bit of research on this found this discussion https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/49843 but it didn't gave me a way.
